Nextjs app can't fetch data for SSG from running backend service (container), build failed with Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
I have a setup like this in my production compose.yml file.
services:
   
  proxy:
    container_name: app-proxy
    image: nginx:1.25.5
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    depends_on:
      - frontend
    networks:
      - app-net

  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    image: my-org/nextjs-frontend:prod
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: .docker/prod/Dockerfile
    command: ["node", "server.js"]
    depends_on:
      - backend
    networks:
      - app-net

  backend:
    container_name: app-backend
    image: my-org/wagtail-backend:prod
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - DB_NAME=${DB_NAME}
      - DB_USER=${DB_USER}
      - DB_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - DEBUG=False
      - CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS=${CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS}
    volumes:
      - backend-static:/staticfiles
      - backend-media:/mediafiles
    command: >
      sh -c "
      set -xe;
      python manage.py migrate --noinput;
      gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 backend.wsgi:application
      "
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - app-net
 
  db:
    container_name: app-db
    image: postgres:16.3
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - app-net

volumes:
  backend-static:
  backend-media:
  db-data:

networks:
  app-net:
    driver: bridge

What I did was start the db and backend services with docker compose up backend -d, ensuring they were up and running. I then proceeded to try building the image for the frontend (which is a Next.js app) with docker build frontend, because the frontend needs to fetch data from the backend (up and running blissfully) for pre-rendering pages during its build process with yarn (specified in its Dockerfile).The error I got from this build was a network error stating that it can't resolve the backend service. Here’s the error message:
32.83       at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12618:11
32.83       at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
32.83     cause: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND backend
32.83         at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26)
32.83         at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:128:17) {
32.83       errno: -3001,
32.83       code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
32.83       syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
32.83       hostname: 'backend'
32.83     }

Can anyone tell me why I get this error? Is the backend service exposed to this build process?
The fetch for the backend service is correctly defined in my nextjs codebase because I use the same setup for dev (except without SSG using yarn build).

No, image builds can never connect to other containers.  (The temporary containers produced in image builds aren't connected to any particular Docker network.)  It'd be slightly surprising behavior if the content of an image depended on what was in a container, and the same source code produced different images depending on external context.

Is there a way to attach this temporary container to a specified docker network? What I want is to generate static pages for a nextjs app with data available from the backend. Even if theres no data to work with yet, it should be able to see the backend during this build process of the frontend.
